# how to add text to an output redirected to a file

Tags: linux

I don't know if I'm wording it correctly, but I'm counting file types and outputting the results into a file, and instead of there just being numbers, I'm trying to identify what each number is. Sooo basically right now I have:

```
$ find . -type f -iname *.jpg* | wc -l > Test.md
$ find . -type f -iname *.png* | wc -l >> Test.md
$ find . -type f -iname *.tiff* | wc -l >> Test.md
```

and when I cat Test.md I get:

```
$ cat Test.md
13
10
8
```

and what I'm trying to do is:

```
JPG: 13
PNG: 10
TIFF: 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just add the string without a newline before the count.

```
: > Test.md       # truncate the file
echo -n "JPG: " >> Test.md
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg*' | wc -l >> Test.md
echo -n "PNG: " >> Test.md
find . -type f -iname '*.png*' | wc -l >> Test.md
echo -n "TIFF: " >> Test.md
find . -type f -iname '*.tiff*' | wc -l >> Test.md
```

or like, grab the output of `wc` with command substitution, and pass to `echo` to do some formatting:

```
echo "JPG: $(find . -type f -iname '*.jpg*' | wc -l)" > Test.md
echo "PNG: $(find . -type f -iname '*.png*' | wc -l)" >> Test.md
echo "TIFF: $(find . -type f -iname '*.tiff*' | wc -l)" >> Test.md
```

Note: quote the `*.jpg*` argument for `find` inside single (or double) quotes to prevent filename expansion on the argument. `find` needs the argument with `*`, not literal filenames after the shell expansion.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do using a *here-doc* :

```
cat<<EOF>Test.md
JPG: $(find . -type f -iname '*.jpg*' | wc -l)
PNG: $(find . -type f -iname '*.png*' | wc -l)
TIFF: $(find . -type f -iname '*.tiff*' | wc -l)
EOF
```